# Conceptual problem with incorporating constraints to a particular variational principle problem

Tags: variational-principle, continuum-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

Consider the following problem:

A vector field $\boldsymbol{F}(x)$ is defined over a finite region $V$. A functional of the form
\begin{equation}
U = \int_V u(\boldsymbol{F})\ d^3x
\end{equation}
is to undergo the variation with respect to both $x$ and $\boldsymbol{F}$ but with the constraint that the divergence of the vector field be a particular function, e.g.
\begin{equation}
\text{div} \boldsymbol{F}(x) \equiv F_{i,i}(x) = f(x).
\end{equation}

My attempt is to introduce a Lagrange multiplier, say $\psi(x)$, and have the variation be of the form
\begin{equation}
\delta \{U - \int_V \psi(x) f(x) d^3x\} =0 \ \ \ \Rightarrow  \ \ \ \delta U - \int_V\psi\delta (fd^3x) = \delta U - \int_V \psi \delta f (1 + \delta x_{k,k})d^3x = 0 
\end{equation}
where $(1+\delta x_{k,k})$ is the jacobian of the infinitesimal deformation. Doing so, one has
\begin{equation}
\delta U - \int_V\psi \delta (F_{i,i})(1+ \delta x_{k,k})d^3x =0
\end{equation}

BUT my instructor suggests instead to write
\begin{equation}
\delta U - \int_{V'} \psi \ \text{div}(\delta \boldsymbol{F}) d^3x =0
\end{equation}
where $V'$ is the virtually deformed region of $V$.

I can't see why this is the case. I don't see them as equal, because I don't reckon $\delta$ and div commute in this case, unless $\delta \boldsymbol{F}$ in the latter excludes the convective term $\delta x \cdot \text{grad} \boldsymbol{F}$.
The same question could be relevant to a curl problem. I mean, where a vector field's curl is regarded as a constraint.